# How to create multiple column families in an HBase table using the shell

Tags: hbase

Is the process to have multiple "create" commands against the same table? What is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Syntax would be like this :

```
create '<table name>' , '<column-family1>' , '<column-family2>' etc..
```

Comment: OK that's another way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Answer is to use a ruby list: the following creates a table 'app' with three column familes m, f, c:

```
create 'app',['m','f','c']
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to create `Hbase` table with multiple column families and versions is as follows:

```
create 'test', {NAME => 'e', VERSIONS => 5},{NAME => 'r', VERSIONS => 5},{NAME => 'rm', VERSIONS => 5},{NAME => 'rx', VERSIONS => 5},{NAME => 't', VERSIONS => 5},{NAME => 'w', VERSIONS => 5}
```